# Auth through google oauth with one-time secret

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

Is there a way to implement something like this:

- Client-side (javascript) asking google to provide one time code (secret);
- Google returns a secret code to the client;
- Client make a request to back-end with the secret;
- Back-end verify that secret. Make request to Google with the secret and get back user id like email or so.

If there is, could you point me to google REST endpoints to implement this approach?

**pros**: As I see it now, the way I described above allows me implement stateless and cookieless authentication. The only way to compromise the system is get the access to google account itself.
**cons**: Every API call needs two calls to google (obtain a secret, verify the secret). High load on the server and large latency.

Are there some alternatives?

Comment: What about simply getting people to use their Google account to log in?

Comment: Sounds like the oauth2 token flow is for you. But I am not sure what your question is actually about.

Comment: @gcampbell: I'm ok with normal oauth flow but what I should do after user login? set a cookie? how I will identify a user on any request to my API (backend)? In case of set cookie after login, what if someone steals the cookies (for example MIM attack)? :) thanks!

Comment: @WiktorZychla: I want to identify a user somehow on the backend without setting cookies. :)

Comment: You don't need cookies to idenfity a user once. But somehow you have to persist this to retain the autentication between requests.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: this is why I'm asking - how to "retain" it between requests. :-) Do you have any working solution for it? The security is very important for this solution.

Comment: You could possibly pass tokens in the query string and then generate further links that also contain the token.

Comment: @WiktorZychla ok, which token do you mean? refresh token or access one? or custom one?

Comment: A custom one, once you make use of google's token you don't need it anymore.